# Reference related issue compiling with Visual Studio 2008 but not with g++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, g++, portability

the following code compiles with Visual Studio 2008 **but not with g++ on Mac OSX:**

```
class A
{
public:
  A CreateA()
  {
    A a;
    return a;
  }
  };

class B
{
public:
  void ComputeWithA
    (
    A &a // Here, removing the reference solves the problem
    )
  {
    return;
  }
};

int main ()
{
  A a;
  B b;

  b.ComputeWithA(a); // Works
  b.ComputeWithA(a.CreateA()); // Invalid arguments 'Candidates are: void ComputeWithA(A &)'

  return 0;
}
```

Why this reference related issue? Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a.CreateA()` gives you a R-Value (i.e. a temporary). `ComputeWithA` wants a reference, aka L-Value.  The standard says that you can't convert R- into L-Values, so the MSVC is wrong here.

However, you can take a const reference since this case is explicitly allowed:

```
void ComputeWithA(A const &a) // add a const and everything works fine
```

Answer (score 3):

The code isn't legal but VC is accepting it. Your function returns a temporary, which cannot be bound to a non-const reference (which your function takes as its argument).

Can you change your function to take its parameter by const reference?

Answer (score -1):

If you can't change the signature of the method, there is a workaround

```
class A
{
public:
A& operator()()
{
return *this;
}  
...
b.ComputeWithA(a.CreateA()());
```

I've used this once when implementing a logger, because the temporary object was used in more operations.

Comment: If there are problems with this solution I'll like to now beside being modded down.

Comment: You're still binding a temporary to a non-const reference. Just added one more level of indirection.

Comment: agree, but the compiler will be happy and it will be ok as long as you don't store the reference in the called function.